# Magento 1.6.1: How To Get Tracking Number From Order Object in PHP?

Tags: magento, magento-1.6

How can I find the tracking number associated with each order? I have created a script to output the data. I have tried so many variations, yet they all return blank/null.

Currently, it outputs

```
103236290       United States Postal Service - First-Class Mail Parcel      Mar 23, 2013 10:12:59 PM
```

Note that the output is tab delimited, so there are two tabs between order id and shipment method.

```
<?php

//External script - Load magento framework
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/store/app/Mage.php");
Mage::app('default');

$myOrder=Mage::getModel('sales/order'); 
$ship = Mage::getModel('sales/order_shipment');
$orders=Mage::getModel('sales/mysql4_order_collection');

$trackings=Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_shipment_track_collection')->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addAttributeToFilter('parent_id',$ship->getId());
$trackings->getSelect()->order('entity_id desc')->limit(1);

$trackData = $trackings->getData();
$trackID = $trackData[0]['entity_id'];


$from = "2013-03-24 00:00:00"; // orders from date
$to= "2013-06-20 00:00:00"; // orders to date

//Optional filters you might want to use - more available operations in method _getConditionSql in Varien_Data_Collection_Db. 
$orders->addFieldToFilter('total_paid',Array('gt'=>0)); //Amount paid larger than 0
$orders->addFieldToFilter('status',Array('eq'=>"Complete"));  //Status is: "complete", "processing" "canceled" etc.
$orders->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array(
            'from'  => $from,
            'to'    => $to,                    
        ));
$allIds=$orders->getAllIds();
foreach($allIds as $thisId) {
    $myOrder->reset()->load($thisId);

    echo "<pre>";
    //print_r($myOrder);


    //Fields to print
    echo $myOrder->getRealOrderId() . " ";
    echo $trackID . "   ";
    echo $myOrder->getShippingDescription() . "     ";
    echo $myOrder->getCreatedAtDate() . "   ";



    echo "\r\n";
  echo "</pre>";
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the working script. We figured it out :-)

```
  <?php

//External script - Load magento framework
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/store/app/Mage.php");
Mage::app('default');

$myOrder=Mage::getModel('sales/order'); 
$ship = Mage::getModel('sales/order_shipment');
$orders=Mage::getModel('sales/mysql4_order_collection');

$trackings=Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_shipment_track_collection')->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addAttributeToFilter('parent_id',$ship->getId());
$trackings->getSelect()->order('entity_id desc')->limit(1);

$carrierInstances = Mage::getSingleton('shipping/config')->getAllCarriers();
$carriers['custom'] = Mage::helper('sales')->__('Custom Value');
foreach ($carrierInstances as $code => $carrier) {
if ($carrier->isTrackingAvailable()) {
$carriers[$code] = $carrier->getConfigData('title');
}
}

$from = "2013-03-24 00:00:00"; // orders from date
$to= "2013-06-21 00:00:00"; // orders to date

//Optional filters you might want to use - more available operations in method _getConditionSql in Varien_Data_Collection_Db. 
$orders->addFieldToFilter('total_paid',Array('gt'=>0)); //Amount paid larger than 0
$orders->addFieldToFilter('status',Array('eq'=>"Complete"));  //Status is: "complete", "processing" "canceled" etc.
$orders->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array(
            'from'  => $from,
            'to'    => $to,                    
        ));
$allIds=$orders->getAllIds();
foreach($allIds as $thisId) {
    $myOrder->reset()->load($thisId);

    echo "<pre>";
    //print_r($myOrder);


    //Some random fields
    echo $myOrder->getRealOrderId() . " ";
    $trackings = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_shipment_track_collection')
            ->setOrderFilter($myOrder)
            ->getData();

        foreach ($trackings as $tracking) {
            echo $tracking['track_number'] . "  ";
        }
    echo $carriers[$tracking['carrier_code']] . "   ";
    echo $myOrder->getCreatedAtDate() . "   ";



    //  echo "'" . $myOrder->getStatus() . "',";
    //  echo "'" . $myOrder->getBillingAddress()->getLastname() . "',";
    //  echo "'" . $myOrder->getTotal_paid() . "',";
    //  echo "'" . $myOrder->getShippingAddress()->getTelephone() . "',";
    //  echo "'" . $myOrder->getPayment()->getCc_type() . "',"; // bad code
    echo "\r\n";
  echo "</pre>";
    }

?>
```